# My SQL database sequelize npm

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Hear i connect mysql database using sequelize npm

```
    const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
    var sequelize = new Sequelize('custom_crm', 'root', '', {
        host: "localhost",
        port: 3306,
        dialect: 'mysql'
    });
    sequelize.authenticate().then(() => {
        console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
    });

    sequelize.query("SELECT id,name FROM `asd123`.`items` WHERE id = 5 LIMIT 1").spread((results, metadata) => {
      console.log("results >>",results);
    });
```

i want convert asd123(database) query in using below sequelize schema type.

```
website_videos = sequelize.define('website_video', {
  id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true },   
  name : { type: Sequelize.CHAR}
});
website_videos.findAll({}).then((data) => {
  console.log('data',data[0]['dataValues']);
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
website_videos.findAll(
    {
        where: {
            id: user_id
        },
        limit: 1,
        attributes:["id","name"],
    }).then((data) => {
        console.log('data', data[0]['dataValues']);
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
})
```

;